# Node Permissioning over Governance Smart Contract has problems in OpenEthereum Chain

Tags: private-blockchain, openethereum, permissioned-chain

I work at a supply chain solution that uses a Private, Permissioned, Open Ethereum Chain. Everything is configured over Smart Contracts (Permissioning / Validators / Allowed Nodes). These have an initial configuration set in the constructor and then can be modified over a voting process. The initial configuration works fine. However, adding a new node over the governance does not work. The nodePermissioning Contract is successfully updated, and the "connectionAllowed" function returns the correct value when querying if the new node can connect to the existing ones. However, the new node can not connect to the network. When searching for the problem, I read that I need to update the nodePermissioning Contract on each machine. However, this poses a problem. First, the new node is usually not permitted to make updating calls. Second, only the governance process is allowed to add new nodes; otherwise, everyone could change which nodes can connect, which would go against the idea of a governed private network. Third, I do not understand how this solution would work and why each node needs to send an update transaction. This goes against everything I learned about blockchains and shared Smart Contracts where everyone agrees on their state.

My question is, how can I make a nodePermissioning contract work that is managed over an on-chain governance process (multiple Smart Contracts)? Second, is the nodePermissioning contract somehow treated specially, and if so, how does it work?

Edit: After looking in the code on git, it seems that the nodePermissioning contract is not handled specially, and the problem stems from new nodes using the genesis block state to evaluate if they are allowed to connect to a node, which always returns false as they were not part of the network at genesis. But because of that, they can not sync and will never get to the block where they are part of the network. This does not answer the first question but changes its context, as it may well be that it is impossible to use an on-chain protocol to govern the network layer (nodePermissioning)

Comment: After looking into the Open Ethereum GitHub code, it seems that the nodePermissioning  contract is not treated specially (to my understanding), which is what could cause the problem. When a new unsynced node is started, it uses the latest state it knows to evaluate if a connection is allowed, as the node is not yet synced. This is the state of the genesis block where the new node is not yet part of the network (which will change in a later block when the governance adds is). However, this means the new node can not connect to any other node and will never be able to sync to that block.

Comment: Check the genesis.json of the network if there's something that says "Node Ingress smart contract" or "nodePermissioning contract" and if that has the address of your nodePermissioning contract. I think the way it should work is: new node gets the chain's genesis, gets the address of the nodePermissioning contract, checks if this new node's enode is in there and then connects. The enode prior to this is added to the contract by the governance dapp.

Comment: Thanks, the nodePermissioning contract is set correctly and works well in the static case. meaning everything that is in this contract from genesis works. The problem arises when the on-chain governance adds a new node later (say in Block X). Now if this new node starts it gets the contract and checks if its in there, but it is not because it uses the state at the genesis block where it is not in there, as it will only be added in Block X. But the new node can not get to block X because it can not sync, because it is not allowed to connect to others based on the genesis state.